# I have a background video on loop and it works perfectly on desktop, but when i see it on mobile it doesn't play

Tags: css, html

Works perfectly on all sizes in a desktop or notebook computer, but when i see it on a mobile it looks like the image.

```css
.video {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  z-index: -100;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<video controls autoplay muted loop id="myVideo">
    <source src="img/Smartphone - 3180.webmsd.webm" type="video/webm">
 </video>
```

[In mobile instead of autoplaying it stays like that, the video is in webm format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJSJx.jpg)

Comment: Hi @juan, Please refer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38893692/html-video-not-working-on-mobile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of mobile browsers do not support autoplay on mobile devices, however, on updated versions of chrome for android, as well as browsers on iOS, they should be able to autoplay the video as long as it is muted.

[Check out this answer as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20499341/html5-video-autoplay-on-mobile-browser)

Edit:
Looks like you also need to have the attribute playsinline on your video element for it to work.

```
<video controls autoplay muted playsinline></video>
```

[This forum mentioned the playsinline attribute that is needed to work](https://forum.webflow.com/t/html5-video-autoplay-now-working-on-mobile/40584/5)