# HTML Video failing on mobile

Tags: reactjs, video, html5-video, mobile-website, react-player

I'm playing a video in [ReactPlayer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-player) that generates an HTML5 video in a `<video>` tag. It's not working on mobile (tested on Safari, Chrome, and Firefox on iPhone 8 iOS 13.5.1)

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38893692/html-video-not-working-on-mobile) which let me know to disable `autoplay` and add `playsinline` for mobile, but it's still not working for me. The file I'm pulling, if it's relevant, is hosted on Google Cloud Storage

```
<div id="ReactPlayer" style="margin: auto; border-radius: 10px; min-height: 360px; min-width: 640px; display: block; width: 80%; height: 80%;">
  <video src="link_to_my_video" preload="auto" controls="" playsinline="" webkit-playsinline="" x5-playsinline="" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
  </video>
</div>
```

Does anyone know how to make it play on mobile? Thanks

**EDIT**

If helpful my links look like

`"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/my-mvp.appspot.com/o/videos%sub-folder?alt=media&token=my_token"`

and the video it's pulling in is a `.webm` file

Answer (score 0):

For me, what worked was recording the video using `mp4` instead of `webm`. This opens the issue of Chrome only being able to record using the `webm` MIME type, so you're essentially choosing between recording on Chrome, and Viewing on mobile devices. I don't have a clear answer on making video universal across all browsers

I will leave this question open in the hopes that someone can come up with a better solution